# rhel configure: limit root direct login to systems except through system consoles

Tags: security, ssh, rhel5, pam

I have to configure to limit root direct access except system consoles. That is, the ways of telnet, ftp, **SSH** are all prohibited. Root can only login through console.
I understand that will require me to configure the file /etc/securetty. I have to comment all the tty, just keep "console" in /etc/securetty.

But from google, I found many peoples said that configure /etc/securetty will not limit the way of **SSH** login.

From my experiment, I found it is. (configure /etc/securetty won't limit SSH login).

And I add one line in /etc/pam.d/system-auth:
 `auth        required      pam_securetty`

It seems root **SSH** login can be prohibited.

But I can't find the reason: **What is the difference of configure pam_securetty and /etc/securetty?** Can anyone help me with this? Only configure /etc/securetty could work? Or Have I to configure pam_securetty at the same time?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pam_securetty is a PAM module that allows root logins only if the user is logging in on a "secure" tty, as defined by the listing in /etc/securetty. pam_securetty also checks to make sure that /etc/securetty is a plain file and not world writable.

telnet and ftp call login, and you probably already have /etc/pam.d/login including pam_securetty

Comment: Yes, you are right, I checked /etc/pam.d/login, and it really include pam_securetty. Does that means, if without pam_securetty in /etc/pam.d/login, only configure /etc/securetty won't take effective?

Comment: that's right.  you need pam_securetty in /etc/pam.d/whatever